# Is there a way to copy or select partial text from a tree node in a tree view? c#

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, .net-3.5

I am trying to select and copy text from a tree node in C#. 
When I select the node, whole of the text is selected. Is there 
a way around so that I can copy only some text from the node?

E.g., for the child node shown below, is there a way to select and copy text 'This'?

[image: For the child node, is there a way to select and copy text 'This']

I am using `Clipboard.SetText(sDesiredText)` on treeview keydown event.

Comment: WPF? ASP.NET MVC 4/5? ASP.NET Core MVC? WinForms? ASP.NET WebForms? Please [edit] the question and clarify.

Comment: The simplest way is to copy the entire node and then edit the results.  Otherwise, you are going to have to create the node(s) which is more coding.

Comment: @jdweng, I cannot  process the data from the selected node. The text will be randomly selected from the user interface.

Comment: @dbc,  I am using Clipboard.SetText(sDesiredText) on treeview keydown even